# Start Express Server Azure Release Pipeline

Tags: node.js, linux, azure, npm, azure-devops

I have an NPM task in my release pipeline that runs `npm start` which in turn runs an express app with `node server.js`. This task blocks my pipeline because the express process never exits and the task never completes.

What is the best way to work around this? Ideally would need a cross platform solution.

Comment: you are deployging to app service?

Comment: @Sajeetharan No to an VM with an agent installed.

Comment: Did you get any error in your build pipeline? If you do , what's the detail error message? Please also enables verbose logging.